# How to reduce the no of polygons of 3D model using 3DS Max 9.0

Tags: 3dsmax

I have an OBJ Model which is very heavy i want to reduce the size of the model and the model is very fine mesh, i want to reduce the no of polygons.. i need that model to be imported into an iphone application.

Answer (score 10):

There are several solutions. In 3ds Max, you could use the Optimize modifier or the Multires modifier. Outside of 3ds Max, you could use Meshlab to process the OBJ, then import into 3ds Max.

Answer (score 3):

Polygon Cruncher is a plugin for 3DS Max that lets you preview the resulting model before optimization: 
http://www.mootools.com/plugins/us/polygoncruncher/index.asp

Answer (score 2):

Inside max try the prooptimizer modifier.

The Graphite modeling tools have tools that could help.

Topogun http://www.topogun.com/ takes some getting used to but is very nice.

Search for retopo and you will find lots of scripts and programs.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are all possible ways to attack this, but the issue is that they all tend to produce problematic meshes - awkward-looking smoothing, polygons with too many sides, and all semblance of edge flow will be destroyed.

Especially if you need the mesh to deform during animation, the best solution is to have a modeler go in and redo the topology. Even with the aid of automated tools like the Optimize modifier, you will need a modeler who is familiar with the issues involved to oversee the optimization, and to clean up problem areas.